# xtext: How to disable textual input validation for generated xtext plugins (dsl)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext, lexer, mwe

In Xtext there are few different kinds of validations which xtext takes care automatically. Is there any possibility to disable them?

- Lexer/Parser: Syntactical Validation
- Linker: Crosslink Validation

I am trying to disable the parser/lexer for being able to edit very huge files into a dsl editor. As far as I can see it is not possible to do from mwe2 workflow, as following fragment is the entry point for being able to open the editor.

fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment auto-inject {}

I have mentioned that **InternalMysDslLexer** class is instantiated many times while I am typing something.
Should I override this class? what would be the correct approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To disable linking override ILinker in your Runtime module:

```
public Class<? extends ILinker> bindILinker() {
    return MyLinker.class;
}
```

And then override doLinkModel() to do noting (only for huge files I guess):

```
public class MyLinker extends LazyLinker {
    protected void doLinkModel(final EObject model, IDiagnosticConsumer consumer) {}
}
```

Not sure what you mean by saying you want to disable syntax validation. This would disable all the Xtext features. Isn't it better to simply edit huge files using a regular text editor instead of Xtext one?

There's also a lot of resources on Xtext performance on SO, [Eclipse Xtext community forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=27), 
and various blogs.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I am looking for this solution over a week. And also posted on Xtext community,but didn't received many help on it.So far, I have canceled jobs XtextReconcilerJob, Xtext Validation and Refreshing outline, but the typing is still slow. I also would suggest rather to used plain text editor, but I am not the one who decides about this.

Comment: Use a Java profiler and see where the time is spent. Hard to tell not knowing your setup and how big the files are.

Comment: Is it possible to do same for lexer? or how to build a simplified lexer.

Comment: It makes no sense at all to disable a lexer. Not sure if anyone ever tried it. If your user explicitly wants to use an Xtext editor you should let him use it - no matter how slow it is. And yes - it's possible to write a simplified lexer. But you don't even know what takes so much time in you application. Start with profiling.